# In-house OS X app updater - handling of "signature folder"?

Tags: macos, auto-update, updating

I am in the process of adapting our custom (auto-)updater to work with OS X apps. (These OS X apps will be distributed outside of the Mac App Store.)

After the new bundle is downloaded, I am selectively overwriting certain files. However, it is unclear to me whether there is a situation where I should also overwrite the `_CodeSignature` folder in the "old" app with the newer one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As (currently) the Gatekeeper checks a downloaded app only the first time it is run, the above becomes a non-issue (again: for the time being).